# TabBar Images not showing in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I'm developing an app that has iOS 7.1 as its Deployment Target. So far everything works just fine, however there is one huge issue, the tab bar images are not showing up. This is confusing, because they show up when running on the iOS 8 Simulator, I'm using the Xcode 6 beta 1.

I've set up two images. The dimensions are 60x60 and 70x60. So size does not seem to be an issue. I've set the images up in Interface Builder. When logging the tab bar image to the console however, it returns nil. I've then tried setting the images up in code, and using the same method to log it to the console, I now have a memory address for the image, but it still does not show up.

When searching for an answer on Google and stackoverflow, I've found this method:

```
        self.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
NSLog(@"%@", self.tabBarItem.image);
```

This worked for some users apparently, but not for me. I can not figure this out, I'd be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Are you sure you have an image named "IMAGE"? There's no reason why this code wouldn't work, unless A) self.tabBarItem doesn't exist (=nil) or B) the image doesn't exist

Comment: I replaced my original name with "IMAGE" for this post. When setting the image in Interface Builder, and then logging it to the console in my view controller, I get nil. When I then set the image up in my controller, and log the image, I get a memory adress, but the image still won't show up.

Comment: You've added this into UITabBarController class?

Comment: I have a UITableViewController subclass that is connected to the tab bar in my Storyboard. The relationship exists, otherwise the tab wouldn't show up at all in the simulator. I tried setting up the image in the controller as stated above, in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I have a UITableViewController subclass that is connected to the tab bar? I don't understand... Could you post an image of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get the tab bar image for my view controller to show up. I have a UITabBarController in my storyboard, and a UITableViewController that is connected to it. Setting the image in Interface Builder works for iOS 8, but not for iOS 7.1. In iOS 8 it shows up, like it should, but it does not appear at all in iOS 7.1. Setting it up in code also does not work.

Comment: I have a feeling you're mixing up UITabBarController with UITabBar. The Tab bar is intended to navigate between view controllers (like the in the AppStore). If you'd like to just show something, consider using a UIToolbar instead.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm expressing myself in an unclear way. I have a tab bar. As you certainly know, tab bars have images for each tab (or icons if you will) and not just text. And these images do not appear in my application. And I'm trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling about what you're doing, but it's still not clear.

You have a tab bar, but you have an outlet to the tab bar item itself.

That's not the way you would do it. You create an outlet to the tab bar, then add custom items with:

```
UIImage *defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"];
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"];
UITabBarItem *itemZero = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item One" image:defaultImage selectedImage:selectedImage];

UITabBarItem *itemOne = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item Two" image:defaultImage selectedImage:selectedImage];

NSArray *items = @[itemZero,itemOne];
[self.tabBar setItems:items animated:animated];
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, I have my TabBarController set up in my Storyboard. When adding ViewControllers to it, the tab bar items are automatically created, and you can set the title, and the image. So I can then reference it in my code, without setting an outlet, using self.tabBarItem because I have my Controller connected to the TabBarController. I hope that makes sense.